# Libgdx : how to attach actor to a rotated group

Tags: libgdx

I have a group actor with a circle image .png and then I spread small circles around surface of this group, I mean circle on angle 0 and circle on angle 60 and so on using the math equation:

```
x=cx+radius*cos(theta);
y=cx+radius*sin(theta);
```

The problem now I apply rotate action (rotateBy Action)on the main group and I want to add circle actor to this rotated group when the user tab note: this circle actor is not yet child of the main circle rotated group. I want to add this actor to the rotated group and show to the user as it attached to point of collision with surface of circle of the main group. See the image.
Sorry for my bad English.

**image before:**

[image: image before]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v2f0.jpg

**image after:**

[image: image after]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo1Rn.jpg

Comment: I was only editing. I don't know what's wrong and I don't know anything about libgdx.

Comment: ok then what is  suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its pure maths...

find the collision point coordinates relative to origin of the group(x_rel, y_rel)

than add the actor to the group

```
addActor(newBall);
newBall.setPosition(x_rel, y_rel);
```